# Delete comment operator(#) from beginning of selected lines

Tags: file

[image]

I want to remove **#** from line 79 to 91

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visual-Block mode:

- Enter in Visual-Block mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>,
- select the first column and
- Hit <kbd>d</kbd>.

But you have also plugins like nerdcommenter (preservim/nerdcommenter) to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

There's different ways to do this.

A solution:

`:79,91g/^#/normal x`

`g` applies a command on the given range. In this case we just delete the first character.

`^#` filters line to keep only those starting with a `#`.

You could also select your lines visually then hit `:g...`. This will automatically limit the command to your selection.

Answer (score 0):

```
:79,91 s/^.//
```

would be my natural answer.

although you did say 'selected' code, which suggests that

:s/^.// would work, although it will show up as

```
:'<,'>s/^.//
```

This deletes the first character regardless of if it's a #, which is fine here, but might not be what you want in general.